# Netsuite - Cannot set the restock=T for itemreceipt line items

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Can anyone tell me how to set the restock boolean value for a line item on an item receipt. This is what im trying to do but it is not taking:

`itemReceipt.selectLineItem('item', placeholder.lineNumber);
itemReceipt.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', 1);
itemReceipt.setCurrentLineItemValue("item", "restock", true);`

According to the Schema Browser docs this is the correct but it does not work? Am I doing something wrong. Also tried 1 and 0. I am not new to NetSuite api, just having issues setting this field. The other fields set just fine

Comment: Have you tried 'T' instead of true?

Comment: yes I have. also tried 1 and o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many boolean fields in NetSuite take 'T' or 'F' as their expected values, as opposed to the completely logical true/false of Javascript. Welcome to NetSuite.

Make sure you're using uppercase 'T' or 'F'

Comment: yessir. tried that too as I have learned that the hard way ;)

Comment: This was it. It was a typo. I was using a lowercase t with no quotations. This is what I get for using notepad...fml

Comment: Testing myself, T and F work as expected for the restock field